# SSL Certificate from GoDaddy on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, google-compute-engine

I am trying to add an `SSL Certificate` to my Virtual Machine Instance on Google Compute Engine I created the key file and generated a `CSR File`, which I copied into GoDaddy to request a `SSL Certificate`.

I copied what they sent me and pasted it into a file name `example.csr`
I then ran this line in the instance:

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create certificate1 --certificate example.csr --private-key example.key
```

When I list my ssl-certificates I get:

```
NAME             CREATION_TIMESTAMP
certificate1     2017-03-08T09:21:04.166-08:00
```

But I can't figure out why my webapp is not secure yet. When I go into my url it still says not secure.

**EDIT**

Source: [SSL Certificates, Compute Engine Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ssl-certificates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**
We can't do that yet.

**Medium Length Answer:**
I had to actually install the SSL certificate directly on my application.

Answer (score 1):

Although I've never used Google Compute Engine, I believe (after reading the documentation you linked) that you've just added the certificate, but you still need to configure it:

> To use HTTPS or SSL load balancing, you must create an [SslCertificate resource](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/v1/sslCertificates) that can be used by your target proxy.
>
> **Note:** SslCertificate resources are used only with load balancing
>   proxies such as a [target HTTPS proxy](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/target-proxies) or [target SSL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/tcp-ssl/). See that
>   documentation for when and how to use SslCertificate resources.
>   SslCertificate resources are not used on individual instances. On an
>   instance, install the normal SSL certificate as described in your
>   application documentation.

I suggest reading the links provided by the docs (above), depending of what you want to do (use a HTTPS proxy, SSL proxy or individual instance).